# constant coefficient of an ODE, I did a proof but something it´s wrong

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let an homogeneous ODE with constant coefficient $
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {a_k y^{\left( k \right)} }  = 0
$ with clearly $ a_k$ denotes the constants, and $
y^{\left( k \right)}  = \frac{{d^k y}}
{{dx^k }}
$.   I have a question about a proof that I did, it´s obviously bad, it´s a known fact that if $
\lambda 
$ is a solution of the associated polynomial $
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {a_k x^k } 
$ then $
e^{\lambda x} 
$ it´s a solution. And if $
\lambda 
$ has algebraic multiplicity m>1 (clearly $
m \leqslant n
$)
 then other LI solutions, are $$
\lambda e^{\lambda x} ,\lambda ^2 e^{\lambda x} ,...\lambda ^{m - 1} e^{\lambda x} 
$$
My question it´s about this fact, I want to prove it , But look something. Let´s take a function of the form $
f\left( x \right) = \lambda ^j e^{\lambda x} 
$ let´s check if it´s a solution. Then we replace $$
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {a_k \left( {f\left( x \right)} \right)^{\left( k \right)} }  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {a_k \left( {\lambda ^j e^{\lambda x} } \right)^{\left( k \right)} }  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {a_k \lambda ^j \left( {e^{\lambda x} } \right)^{\left( k \right)} }  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {a_k \lambda ^j \lambda ^k e^{\lambda x} }  = \lambda ^j e^{\lambda x} \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {a_k \lambda ^k } 
$$
the last step it was because that terms are constant in the sum. But $$
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {a_k \lambda ^k }=0 
$$ thus  $
\lambda ^j e^{\lambda x} 
$ it´s a solution , the problem is that this is valid for every $
j \in R
$ but the functions of the form $$
\lambda ^j e^{\lambda x} 
$$ are always LI if the j are distinct, so we have more than n LI solutions , this it´s false, so my proof it´s false, But I don´t know where is the mistake
addition to showing what is wrong, I could help with this event please, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The solutions should be 
$$e^{\lambda x}, xe^{\lambda x},\dots, x^{m-1}e^{\lambda x}$$
instead of 
$$e^{\lambda x} ,\lambda e^{\lambda x} ,...\lambda ^{m - 1} e^{\lambda x}.$$

Comment: Ok, But the proof it´s what I need , and I writed that, I don´t understand your answer =S